# GlobIterator prepends / slash to local filenames

Tags: php

So I was trying to use [`GlobIterator`](http://php.net/GlobIterator) for unifying some file parameter handling. (Using the Iterator for symmetry with the also used [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) for other list params.)

But it has a peculiarity with filespecs for the current directory:

```
 $dir = new GlobIterator("*.php");
```

That prepends `/` slashes to keys and `FileObject` entry names.

```
     [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /index.php
     [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => /index.php
```

Which makes utilizing it as filename iterator less useful.

So `GlobIterator` is not merely a 1:1 [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) replacement wrapped in an Iterator as the manual suggests. **(1)** But why does the `/` get prepended anyway? **(2)** And which flag does disable this rewrite? [`FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO`](http://php.net/FilesystemIterator) was my first assumption, but didn't help, neither `::KEY_AS_PATHNAME`. Are there other flags? (terse manual and all)

Comment: Any volunteers for the [source code diving](http://y3.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=ext/spl/spl_iterators.c;hb=refs/heads/master)?  (Link is to the new official PHP git repo.  [Here's the rest of SPL](http://y3.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=tree;f=ext/spl;hb=refs/heads/master).)

Comment: I can't even test...my GlobIterator::next() [throws an exception](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55701). You could use splFileInfo->getBasename()

Comment: Can't make much sense of it. But it seems to hinge on the `glob://*` stream wrapper rather. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L698 - Either way it's probably desired behaviour, all versions and Windows' php.exe exhibit the behaviour.

Comment: @Marek: The manual page says `Iterates through a file system in a similar fashion to glob().`. Now I concede "similar" might also mean "somewhat like, but not quite exactly like", but that is not what it suggests. (I'll use the docs editor...)

Comment: @mario The question is wrong because it's based on a false assumption that the manual says GlobIterator is a 1:1 replacement of glob(). As I pointed out, it isn't the case. Your accepted solution is therefore not based on GlobIterator. The question should ask: what can I use instead of glob()?

Comment: @Marek: Well, nope. The question as for the why still stands. Also please don't, citations with left out words are no citations at all.

Comment: @mario My inquiry was about the question based on a wrong premise. If I were you I'd edit that. GlobIterator is simply not an exact replacement for glob().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the old chinese proverb says, if you want an iterator that gives you an output similar to [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob), then just use a frigging iterator over glob.

So I just resorted to that:

```
 $list = [
      new ArrayIterator(glob("*.php")),
      new ArrayIterator(glob("whatevers/*.php")),
      new RII(RecursiveDirectoryIterator("more")),
 ]
```

That gives the expected unified filename list without `(strstr($glob,"/") ? "$glob" : "./$glob")` wrapping or key/value probing within app logic.

Comment: "✔" means this might not be the best approach, but does what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

One can output file names without the leading slash as following:

```
<?php
$iterator = new GlobIterator("*.php");
$iterator->setFlags(FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
echo "Key as Filename:\n";
foreach ($iterator as $key => $fileinfo) {
    echo $key . "\n";
}
?>
```

output:

```
Key as Filename:
apple.jpg
banana.jpg
example.php
```

[GlobIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) extends [FilesystemIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php). Applicable constants for [setFlags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystemiterator.setflags.php) are well [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants).

Comment: Well, that's not quite the symmetry I was looking for (I'd still have to pre-check the glob pattern, don't get working relative paths for `*.php` and `dir/*.php` alike as with `glob()`) but that sheds some light on it. (`_AS_FILENAME` only gives me the basename and `KEY_AS_PATHNAME` still has that peculiarity.)

Comment: @mario it'd be certainly nice if the "symmetry" you are looking for existed, but realistically there is nothing like a magic flag to completely change the behavior of GlobIterator from its current to your designated. This is the best you can get. Use $fileinfo to access extended information and $key to get the filename. Side note: pathinfo() may be handy when parsing information from paths. If you think GlobIterator should be a 1:1 replacement of glob(), you may want to add a feature request on PHP wish list.